# Strict secure cookies vs. cookie prefixes

Tags: web-browser, cookies

The `secure` flag on cookies prevent them from being read by an insecure (non-HTTPS) site, but they can still be written or deleted from an insecure site. There are two new browser features that try to prevent that:

- [Strict Secure Cookies](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4506322921848832)
- [Cookie Prefixes](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4952188392570880)

It seems to me that the `__Secure-` prefix also makes the cookie strictly secure.

How do these two features compare with each other? Why are there two seperate solutions for overwriting cookies? Do I still need the cookie prefix if my clients have a browser with strict secure cookie support?

Comment: Just pointing out / clarifying that the secure flag prevents cookies from being sent on insecure connections. What do you mean when you state that they can still be deleted from an insecure site ?

Comment: @niilzon, secure attribute ensures confidentiality but not the integrity. Consider abc.test.com and def.test.com. abc.test.com can set a cookie with domain as test.com which can possibly overwrite, say, a secure, test.com cookie set by def.test.com

Answer (score 7):

The [strict secure cookies draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-leave-secure-cookies-alone-05#section-4) describes a limitation of strict secure cookies where cookie prefixes can help:

> The mitigations in this document do not, however, give complete
> confidence that a given cookie was set securely.  If an attacker is
> able to impersonate a response from "http://example.com/" before a
> user visits "https://example.com/", the user agent will accept any
> cookie that the insecure origin sets, as the "secure" cookie won't
> yet be present in the user agent's cookie store.  An active network
> attacker may still be able to use this ability to mount an attack
> against "example.com", even if that site uses HTTPS exclusively.

If there is no cookie yet, an insecure origin can set a secure cookie, but not a prefixed cookie. So cookie prefixes are still a good idea when using browsers that implement strict secure cookies.